# Stacking monads Writer and OptionT

Tags: scala, monad-transformers, scala-cats, writer-monad

I have the following code:

```
override def getStandsByUser(email: String): Try[Seq[Stand]] =
  (for {
    user <- OptionT(userService.findOneByEmail(email)): Try[Option[User]]
    stands <- OptionT.liftF(standService.list()):[Try[List[Stand]]]
    filtered = stands.filter(stand => user.stands.contains(stand.id))
  } yield filtered).getOrElse(Seq())
}
```

I want to add logging on each stage of the processing - so I need to introduce writer monad and stack it with monad transformer OptionT. Could you please suggest how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do this is to convert your service calls into using `cats-mtl`.

For representing `Try` or `Option` you can use `MonadError` and for logging you can use `FunctorTell`. Now I don't know what exactly you're doing inside your `userService` or `standService`, but I wrote some code to demonstrate what the result might look like:

```
type Log = List[String]

//inside UserService
def findOneByEmail[F[_]](email: String)
  (implicit F: MonadError[F, Error], W: FunctorTell[F, Log]): F[User] = ???

//inside StandService
def list[F[_]]()
  (implicit F: MonadError[F, Error], W: FunctorTell[F, Log]): F[List[Stand]] = ???

def getStandsByUser[F[_]](email: String)
(implicit F: MonadError[F, Error], W: FunctorTell[F, Log]): F[List[Stand]] =
  for {
    user <- userService.findOneByEmail(email)
    stands <- standService.list()
  } yield stands.filter(stand => user.stands.contains(stand.id))


//here we actually run the function
val result =
  getStandsByUser[WriterT[OptionT[Try, ?], Log, ?] // yields WriterT[OptionT[Try, ?], Log, List[Stand]]
    .run  // yields OptionT[Try, (Log, List[Stand])]
    .value // yields Try[Option[(Log, List[Stand])]]
```

This way we can avoid all of the calls to `liftF` and easily compose our different services even if they will use different monad transformers at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the definition of `cats.data.Writer` you will see that it is an alias to `cats.data.WriterT` with the effect fixed to `Id`.

What you want to do is use `WriterT` directly and instead of `Id` use `OptionT[Try, YourType]`.

Here is a small code example of how that can be achieved:

```
object Example {

  import cats.data._
  import cats.implicits._

  type MyType[A] = OptionT[Try, A]

  def myFunction: MyType[Int] = OptionT(Try(Option(1)))

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val tmp: WriterT[MyType, List[String], Int] = for {
      _ <- WriterT.tell[MyType, List[String]](List("Before first invocation"))
      i <- WriterT.liftF[MyType, List[String], Int](myFunction)
      _ <- WriterT.tell[MyType, List[String]](List("After second invocation"))
      j <- WriterT.liftF[MyType, List[String], Int](myFunction)
      _ <- WriterT.tell[MyType, List[String]](List(s"Result is ${i + j}"))
    } yield i + j

    val result: Try[Option[(List[String], Int)]] = tmp.run.value
    println(result)
    // Success(Some((List(Before first invocation, After second invocation, Result is 2),2)))
  }

}
```

The type annotations make this a bit ugly, but depending on your use case you might be able to get rid of them. As you can see `myFunction` returns a result of type `OptionT[Try, Int]` and `WriterT.lift` will push that into a writer object that also has a `List[String]` for your logs.